# How to fill a listpicker with object name in Windows phone?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, binding, listpicker

The problem is that I have to fill out a ListPicker with the objects that I have saved in the database, but only with the object name.

I can populate the list using the ItemsSource property, but the list is being populated with the following "`Traveler.Model.Car`", and I need the correct name of each object.

After that, still need to use their property, but this is easier.

```
Xaml:
<toolkit:ListPicker Name="lpCars" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"/>

 private void GetCarList()
        {            
            using (UtilsManagerDataBase getList = new UtilsManagerDataBase())
            {
                this._cars.Items = new ObservableCollection<Car>(getList.GetCarList());                
            }      
        }
```

Comment: what do you mean with 'correct object name'? is it value of property 'Name' in 'Car' class that you want to display?

Comment: if the answer of my later question is yes.. then you may want to set attribute DisplayMemberPath="Name" of the ListPicker in xaml

Comment: Yes is it! I'll test!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would help.

Make a listpicker like this in your xaml.

```
<toolkit:ListPicker Name="lstCars" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="220" >
                <toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate >
                    <DataTemplate >
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding PropertyName}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
                <toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate >
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding PropertyName}" FontSize="28"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
            </toolkit:ListPicker>
```

an assign the list as an itemsource to the listpicker in c#
like

lstCars.ItemSource=Your List;